# How is this statement executed

Tags: sql

How is this statement executed,I don't understand the steps it takes to get the correct max_score.

```
create or replace view test2_0111 as
select CID,
       NAME, 
      (select max(score) 
         from pub.student_course t1 
 where t1.CID = t0.CID) as max_score
  from pub.course t0
```

Comment: It's a correlated sub-query. For each row in the result set, the sub-query is evaluated to get the max_score value for the current row's t0.CID.

Answer (score 0):

This construct is what is known as a sub query. What this does for every row in the table `pub.course` is:

1. Find all records in `pub.student_course` with the same `CID` as the current row. (This is what `where t1.CID = t0.CID` does)
2. Select the aggregate maximum from all these records (this is what `max(score)` does)

This subquery is evaluated for every row in the table `pub.course` seperately.

Comment: so `from pub.course t0` is going to affect sub query? I thought it would execute sub query first and then select the result of this statement.Thanks

Comment: `from pub.course t0` is the actual query. The subquery is a query *within* that query, that gets executed for every result row of the actual query.

Comment: @lllsy to be precise: it's a **scalar** sub-query because it returns a single value (not multiple rows and columns)